# javascript collision detection, d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, collision-detection

Working on a little thing in javascript where im adding elements to an SVG with the d3.js library. The function below runs when a button gets clicked. It simply adds a new circle-element to the SVG. What i need help with is to implement a collision detection so the elements wont get added over each other.

```
    createCircle = function(p) {
    var person = svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", Math.random() * svgWidth)
        .attr("cy", Math.random() * svgHeight)
        .attr("r", 20)      
        .attr("class","person")
        .attr("id","p_"+index)
        .style("fill", p.color);
    index++
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298)?

Comment: Yes, i have. But i am doing it in a slighly different way when im adding the elements. Dit not really manage to implement that example in my code.